# Correct applying of object composition (in PHP)

Tags: php, inheritance, dependency-injection, composition

I've just understood the concept of object composition and why to favor it over inheritance whenever it's possible. But I have yet to understand how to implement it in the best possible way. I've found an approach, which I'm currently almost fine with, but I'd like to know, if I can do better in terms of good software design.

My approach mainly aims at avoiding the major drawback when using composition (you buy its flexibility at the cost of much "pass-through code" in order to "connect" the classes properly, that you've just composed).

So let's say, we have a composition, which takes some files, processes them and produce some sort of output. It consists of one or more data supply classes and one class, that is processing the supplied data. So I generate a "controller"- or "distributor"-class in which I inject all the above classes. Then I connect all of them properly in this distributor class.

Example:

```
// individual data supply class
class DataSupplySubA implements DataSubInterface
{
    public function getFiles(): array
    {
        return ['fileA', 'fileB', 'fileC'];
    }
}

// another data class, which exists, because the data is needed in
// combination with many other individual data supply classes.
class DataSupply implements DataInterface
{
    public function getFiles(): array
    {
        return ['fileD'];
    }

    public function getDir(): string
    {
        return 'dir/to/files/';
    }

    public function getExtension(): string
    {
        return '.txt';
    }
}

// the processing class
class DataProcessor implements ProcessingInterface
{
    private array $files;

    public function addFile(string $file): array
    {
        $this->files[] = $file;
    }

    public function process(string $dir, string $extension): void
    {
        // do something
    }

    public function output(): string
    {
        // do something and return something
    }
}

// the distributor class
class Distributor implements DistributionInterface
{
    private DataSubInterface $dataSub;

    private DataInterface $data;

    private ProcessingInterface $processing;

    public function __construct(
        DataSubInterface $dataSub,
        DataInterface $data,
        ProcessingInterface $processing
    )
    {
        $this->dataSub = $dataSub;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->processing = $processing;
    }

    public function set(): void
    {
        $files = array_merge($this->dataSub->getFiles(), $this->data->getFiles());
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $this->processing->addFile($file);
        }
        $this->processing->process($this->data->getDir(), $this->data->getExtension());
    }

    public function get(): string
    {
        return $this->processing->output();
    }
}
```

On the surface, that looks fine. With the distribution class I avoided the repetitive pass-through code. Else I had to pass the code from DataSupplySubA to DataSupply and from there to DataProcessor. I also seperated the classes as I wanted to and it works. But it creates another repetitive problem:

Let's say I have a lot of composed classes, which are all based on the same distributor class. In order to load my desired composed class, I always have to load the distributor class and tell it (or better, my dependency injection container), which particular classes it needs to build the proper composition.

Example:

```
// in runtime: something like this, with DI container
// you will of course get rid of the new keywords
$composition = new Distributor(new DataSupplySubA(), new DataSupply(), new DataProcessor());
```

For me, that only makes sense, if the classes have to be dynamically composed in runtime. But this is not the case for me, I don't need the classes to be created dynamically, I already know of all possible compositions, I need. And instead of always loading the distributor class, like in the example above, I want to load the individual data supply class, which changes with every composition. So I make two adjustments.

First, I change the distributor class to a trait. Because the distribution will stay the same in all compositions. If not, I create another trait with the adjustments.

Example:

```
// the distributor class
trait Distributor
{
    // inner code stays the same
}
```

Second, in the individual data supply class, I include the distributor trait.

Example:

```
// individual data supply class
class DataSupplySubA implements DataSubInterface, DistributionInterface
{
    use Distributor;

    // either leave the getFiles() function as is or for simplicity reasons make a
    // property out of it and use it in the trait instead of $this->dataSub->getFiles()
}
```

Now I can tell my dependency injection container in its configuration, what dependencies DataSupplySubA, DataSupplySubB, DataSupplySubC etc. needs without having to dynamically compose the classes in runtime, like in the example above with $composition = ...

All problems are now solved for me, so that solution works for me. But I'm not sure, if it's the best possible way. I haven't found a design pattern, which fits these conditions. Composite pattern sounds a bit similar but has obviously nothing to do with it, although I have implemented some sort of it in the data processor class.

And also many programmers are telling you to avoid traits at all or only use it for low level functionality. So there are definitely a few question marks left.

What do you think? How are you handling these problems? Thank you very much in advance for all your answers.

Comment: Your question is currently quite abstract, making it difficult to answer. What would help is if you could support your question with some short code samples that demonstrate the problem and your design. For readability, it works best if you place those code snippets directly after the paragraph mentioning them.

Comment: For instance, it would help if you show one or more of your "data supply classes", their "classes, that are processing the supplied data", and the "controller- or container-class". You might want to explain what you see is "repetitive pass-through code" and point to the code where you "avoided" it. Demonstrate how you "load the container class and tell it" "In order to load [the] desired composed class". And can you demonstrate a simplified version of your composition with this empty class? These additions would hopefully clarify things.

Comment: Thank you. I have uploaded parts of the texts in order to hopefully make my statements a bit clearer now. And I also uploaded code examples, that show my approach.